# Liberty ldap security-role/group mapping not working

Tags: java, web-services, security, ldap, websphere-liberty

In my server.xml I have the following configuration:

```
<enterpriseApplication location="myApp.ear" name="myApp" id="myapp" autoStart="true">
    <classloader commonLibraryRef="global" apiTypeVisibility="spec, ibm-api, api, third-party"/>
    <application-bnd >
        <security-role name="MyAdmin">
            <group name="App.Admin"/>
            <group name="cn=App.Admin,ou=ent,ou=App,ou=apps,o=somedir"/>
            <!--user name="memyselfandi"/-->
            <!--group name="App.Admin" access-id="group:LdapRegistry/cn=App.Admin,ou=ent,ou=App,ou=apps,o=somedir"/-->
        </security-role>
    </application-bnd>
</enterpriseApplication>
```

My subject after the authentication looks like this:

```
    Principal: WSPrincipal:uid=MEMYSELFANDI,ou=person,o=somedir
    Public Credential: com.ibm.ws.security.credentials.wscred.WSCredentialImpl@b29eac,
        realmName=LdapRegistry,
        securityName=MEMYSELFANDI,
        realmSecurityName=LdapRegistry/MEMYSELFANDI,
        uniqueSecurityName=uid=MEMYSELFANDI,ou=person,o=somedir,
        primaryGroupId=null,
        accessId=user:LdapRegistry/uid=MEMYSELFANDI,ou=person,o=somedir,
        groupIds=[SomeOtherGroups, App.Admin]
    Private Credential: CustomLoginModuleCredential
    Private Credential: com.ibm.ws.security.token.internal.SingleSignonTokenImpl@7c2ff51c
```

The **groupIDs** were set by my custom login module, because the group in the ldap registry has no entries in the attribute with the members and thus were not set by standard Liberty login modules. So in my custom module I search for the user in LDAP and add the groups of the entry to the groupIds array of the private credentials:

```
WSCredential credential = (WSCredential) _sharedState.get(com.ibm.wsspi.security.
                auth.callback.Constants.WSCREDENTIAL_KEY);
String[] grpList = ldapEntry.getAttribute("myEntGrps").getValues();
[..]
credential.getGroupIds().add(grpList[i]);
```

**Is there something else I would have to do or is it sufficient to just add the String of the groups to the array?**

I also tried using the securityGroupName (e.g. *cn=myGroup,ou=...*) instead of just the group name (e.g. *myGroup*).

**What would be the right format?**

With this all, when I call my protected servlet, I get the error message:

*CWWKS9104A: Authorization failed for user uid=MEMYSELFANDI,ou=person,o=somedir while invoking myApp on /. The user is not granted access to any of the required roles: [MyAdmin].*

When I change the configuration in the **server.xml** to accept the user *memyselfandi*, I get access. So the configuration is working for users but not groups. I also tried using **access-id**, but this also did not work (my LDAP realm is named LdapRegistry).

In the *trace.log* I see the following (log entry is truncated by Liberty I guess):

```
 ppbnd.internal.authorization.AppBndAuthorizationTableService 3 Added the following subject to role mapping for application: myApp.
    App.Admin
    []
[..]
< updateMapsForAccessId Exit
    {user:LdapRegistry/uid=MEMYSELFANDI,ou=person,o=somedir=[],App.Admin=[]}
```

With user configured in the server.xml, the role is mapped to the user `user:LdapRegistry/uid=MEMYSELFANDI,ou=person,o=somedir=[MyAdmin]`

**Is there some way to test why it is not working? Maybe it's some LDAP configuration issue? What can I set to get the needed log information?** Currently I log:

`traceSpecification="*=info:com.ibm.ws.security.*=all:com.ibm.websphere.security.*=all:com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.security.*=all:com.ibm.ws.wim.*=all"/>`

I would like to know what is processed in the background when the groups are tried to be mapped. Or better, the error I make so that the groups cannot be mapped or found.

Comment: Try updating the groupId list with group:[realm]/[groupname]. For example, it might look like groupIds=[group:LdapRegistry/App.Admin].

Comment: Came here to post my findings and saw your reply. What you suggest was the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some testing, it turns out, that when you add the groups to the subject you have to use the "access-id" format.

So this is what my login module now does:

```
WSCredential credential = (WSCredential) _sharedState.get(com.ibm.wsspi.security.
            auth.callback.Constants.WSCREDENTIAL_KEY);
UserRegistry registry = RegistryHelper.getUserRegistry(credential.getRealmName());
String[] grpList = ldapEntry.getAttribute("myEntGrps").getValues();
[..]
  credential.getGroupIds().add("group:"+credential.getRealmName()+"/"+registry.getGroupSecurityName(grpList[i]));
```

In the end the group entry will look like this:

`group:MyLdapRealm/cn=myGroup,ou..`